# Apple denied renewal of our enterprise program, what are the alternatives?

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise

We're a team of 10, we've been using Apple Enterprise program for years, but recently Apple decided that we are not big enough and doesn't want to renew our program.
I've been looking for alternatives to make an in house private app store, but can't find any. We need something that doesn't have a validation process by Apple when we submit a new app. Usually, the apps on our private app store are used for internal tests, and to show our dev progress to our customers. Do you think of any alternatives to do this ?

Comment: You can just use adhock or even development `ipa` and share them however you want. The main difference is that all devices (and users in case of development IPA) must be in the provisioning profiles you sign the IPA with

Comment: Using an MDM solution you can also distribute the AdHoc builds. (Please note that StackOverflow is not a place for software recommendations, though.) That's how my company did it for years, and still does it when we're not using TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying Apple Business Manager (https://business.apple.com) and Apple School Manager (https://school.apple.com).